# Decimal numbers using CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter

Tags: decimal, formatting

I would appreciate an answer how to solve the following problem.

I use CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter  and I have a problem with formatting decimal numbers in Excel.

Example: I have SQL field TestField, Decimal(15,2)) with value 123.45

When i transfer the result (DataSet and  some C# routine) into Excel with  CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter the result is always 12345 - as though Carlos does not recognizes decimal number correctly.

I tried formatting data on SQL side and on Carlos side and result is always concatenated number (123.45 -> 12345)

A a side note - i did sort of "solve" the problem  by casting the number into varchar but that is not acceptable for our customer because he can not format strings in the excel (like making SUM etc..) and he wants the Excel field to be explicitly numeric not string.

I am almost shure there is some simple answer for that.

Thanks
Damir

I tried Carlos with NumberFormat :

```
            //style2.NumberFormat = "Scientific";                
            //style2.NumberFormat = "General Number";
            //style2.NumberFormat = "###,###.00";
            //style2.NumberFormat = "###.###,00";
```

Answer (score 0):

...

```
case "System.Decimal":
case "System.Double":
wc = new WorksheetCell(dtrrow[col.ColumnName].**ToString().Replace(",",".")**, DataType.Number, style_number);
row.Cells.Add(wc);
```

...